# How can I use VBA to compare two columns and highlight the differences?

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Sub Macro13()
 '
 ' Macro13 Macro
 '

 '

Columns("B:C").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$F2=$G2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Columns("D:E").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$D2=$E2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Columns("F:G").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$F2=$G2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False



End Sub
```

When I do this, it seems to conditional format but I cannot work out what its highlighting.  It's definitely not highlighting different values.

Looking through it seems I have the correct formulas and cell ranges, however I just cannot see where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

Comment: because you have 2 in  `Formula1:="=$F2=$G2"` it conditions the row above the value. Try  `Formula1:="=$F1=$G1"`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot.  I wanted it to start from cell 2 so that's why I did that. Didn't realise it would condition the cell above. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two columns and highlight the difference

```
Sub Highlight()

        Dim n As Integer
        Dim valE As Double
        Dim valI As Double
        Dim i As Integer

        n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For i = 2 To n
        valE = Worksheets("Indices").Range("E" & i).Value
        valI = Worksheets("Indices").Range("I" & i).Value

            If valE = valI Then

            Else:

               Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            End If
        Next i

    End Sub
```

**Second Solution**

[image]

```
Sub CompareColumns()

Dim aRng, bRng As Range
Set aRng = Range("A2:A20")
Set bRng = Range("B2:B6")

For Each aCell In aRng
    For Each bCell In bRng
        If aCell Is Nothing Or bCell Is Nothing Then
        ElseIf aCell.Text = bCell.Text Then
            aCell.Font.Color = bCell.Font.Color
            aCell.Interior.Color = bCell.Interior.Color
        Else
        End If
    Next bCell
Next aCell

End Sub
```